# Parse response to object Facebook API iOS

Tags: ios, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For example, I am getting a profile of mine using Facebook API:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
}];
```

How do I put this response:

```
2014-10-21 16:45:40.435 FacebookTestApp[***] RESULT: {
    "first_name" = Richard;
    gender = male;
    id = *********************;
    "last_name" = Topchiy;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/******/";
    locale = "en_US";
    name = "Richard Topchiy";
    timezone = 3;
    "updated_time" = "2014-05-20T17:34:52+0000";
    verified = 1;
}
```

I can access data like this:

```
  FBGraphObject *obj = (FBGraphObject *)result;
  NSString *str = obj[@"first_name"];
```

But is there any way to work with API like this:

```
FBGraphObject *obj = (FBGraphObject *)result;
NSString *name = obj.first_name;
```

I havent found this in the official documentation, and I cant create "FBGraphUser". Am I doing something wrong, or Facebook has disabled this feature?

Comment: There should be protocols so you can use `FBGraphObject <FBGraphUser>`

Comment: Could you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FBGraphUser` is a protocol. So you can do the following:
`FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *user = (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser>*)result;`